# How do i specify a specific file name in powershell?

Tags: regex, powershell, replace, syntax

I am very new to powershell. I have a csv file that i want to find and replace some text with. after some searching, this seems simple to do, but i still seem to be having problems with the code:

```
$csv = get-content .\test.csv
$csv = $csv -replace "|", "$"
$csv | out-file .\test.csv
```

My file is located here:     C:\Users\CB1\test.csv
How do I specify that location in powershell?

I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
$csv = get-content C:\Users\CB1\test.csv
$csv = $csv -replace "|", "$"
$csv | out-file C:\Users\CB1\test.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't whether you're using relative or absolute paths (assuming your relative paths are relative to the right directory).

Rather, the problem is that the [`-replace`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) operator is [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based, and that `|` is therefore interpreted as a regex *metacharacter* (representing alternation).

Therefore, you need to *escape* such metacharacters, using `\` (or, if you were to do this programmatically, you could use the [`[regex]::Escape()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape) method).

Additionally, since your replacement operation isn't line-specific, you can speed up your operation by reading the file into memory *as a whole*, using the `-Raw` switch.

That, in turn, requires that you use the `-NoNewLine` switch when (re)writing the file.
Also, with *text* input, [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) is preferable to [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) for performance reasons.

To put it all together:

```
(Get-Content -Raw .\test.csv) -replace '\|', '$' | Set-Content -NoNewLine .\test.csv
```

Note: Use the `-Encoding` parameter as needed, as the *input* file's encoding will *not* be honored:

- In *Windows PowerShell*, `Out-File` produces UTF-16LE ("Unicode") files by default, whereas `Set-Content` uses the system's ANSI code page.
- In *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, BOM-less UTF-8 is the consistently applied default.

Comment: Thanks! that worked great. Is there a way to list multiple characters to replace? for example if i wanted to replace: '/|' and ' /'' and '/"' all with '$'?

Comment: @CarloB., use a [character set](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html): `'[|''"]'`